# Unable to delete a record in Mysql

Tags: mysql, delete

Let's say I have table name Company with two columns cname, location.

In the table I am having two records with

cname   |location

Asmetric |Dallas

Sophore |Washington

on this table when I perform a  delete operation

```
delete company where cname='Sophore';
```

I am getting an error

`Error 1064:You have an error in sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your sql server version`

whereas i had expected the complete record to be deleted , is the syntax wrong or it's incomplete.Any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error output is strange, it should be:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'where cname='Sophore'' at line 1
```

Which tell you exactly where the error is- you forgot [the `FROM` clause on DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html):

```
DELETE FROM company WHERE cname='Sophore';
```